# Python: Detect when a variable exceeds an interval of thresholds

Tags: python

I'm looking for way to print a message each time my counter reaches an (in lack of a better phrase) threshold interval. By threshold interval, I mean for instance every new million. E.g.:

```
value exceeds 1 million # Value == 1000001
value exceeds 2 million # Value == 2000014
value exceeds 3 million # Value == 3492090
```

I thought about using something like this:

```
if value % 10**6 == 0:
    print "Message"
```

but that won't work unless the value is a round million, e.g. it won't detect if the new value is 2000001.

Any thoughts?

Comment: To do this you must have the old and the new value at the same time. Can you have it?

Comment: `if (value - 1) % 10**6 == 0:`? Or is the counter potentially incremented by other than one?

Comment: The counter can be incremented by any value, not just 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep track of what million has been exceeded and increment the goal by a million each time.
(this assumes that you're never going to increment more than half a million in one go)

```
counter = 0
nextMillion = 1000000
if counter > nextMillion:
    nextMillion += 1000000
    # Print your message about the counter here.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
threshold = 10**6
old_val = 0

while True:

    # [...] Do your stuff

    val = value // threshold
    if val > old_val
        print "Message"
        old_val = val
```

Answer (score 1):

```
threshold = 10 ** 6
reached = 0

while True:
    _tmp = int(value/threshold)
    if _tmp > reached:
        reached = _tmp
        print "Value reached {}.".format(reached * threshold)
```

Comment: this must be `reached * threshold`

Answer (score 1):

I must have been too fixated on a one-line-solution to not see the simple approach:

```
threshold = 10**6
value = 0

while value < 10*9:
    if value > threshold:
        print "%d exceeded %d" % (value, threshold)
        threshold += 10**6

    value += random.randint(0, 1000)
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Not entirely...what does your code do if `value` is incremented by `n * threshold` ?

Comment: That's a good point @user1016274. This works for my current testing-purposes, but I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For such a minor task there's not much variability, so let's optimize ressources along the way:

```
threshold = 10**6
next_limit = 1 * threshold

def check(value):
    global next_limit

    if value > next_limit:
        next_limit = value // threshold
        print "Value next_limit {} million.".format(next_limit)
```

In Jerome's post, `val` is changed but should not. In contrast to Jamie's code this here will use the least operations for the common case (checking the limit as False) and less ops if the check is successful.